# How to store shards in elasticsearch, when there are to path set(path.data)?

Tags: path, elasticsearch

I have one node elasticsearch cluster, and configure it with two path to store shadrs, like here path.data:/partone,/parttwo. The 1 GB hard disk was mounted on /partone folder and 5 GB hard disk was mounted on /parttwo folder. I used approximately 483 MB file to index, and then 536644 docs appeared in this node. When I remove the hole files in /partone folder, the number of docs became to 531833. It means some of docs were stored in /partone folder.

I read from elasticsearch website as follows:
The multiple data locations allows to stripe it. The striping is simple, placing whole files in one of the locations, and deciding where to place the file based on the location with greatest free space.

And my question is if the striping is based on the location with greatest free space, the hole file should stored in parttwo folder which size is larger than partone folder's, isn't it? Why there exist a small file in folderone?

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph you quoted refers to the actual Lucene index.  There are some details related to how ES performs replication that can also be stored on the smaller drive.  Those get purged as ES flushes data over to Lucene.  For example, with `-Des.path.data=/d/data/foo,/tmp/foo`, after indexing wikipedia for a couple of minutes and performing a `-XPOST /_flush`, I see:

```
% du -ks /d/data/foo /tmp/foo
205680  /d/data/foo
776     /tmp/foo
% df -h /d/data/foo /tmp/foo
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5                      294G   28G  251G  10% /d
/dev/disk/by-uuid/074cc648...  106G   91G   11G  90% /
```

I'm surprised, however, that after deleting some files out of `/partone` that you were able to count the docs.  My index did not function after I removed `/tmp/foo`.